# Can you disable paste on input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, paste

Can you disable the paste function on the Python input() function? (not Tkinter)
If yes, how do you do it?

Here is an example that I am trying to do:

```
newusername=input("Enter new username  ")
usernamecheck=input("Retype username without pasting  ")
```

I am on Windows 10, using Python 3.9.

Comment: What environment are you in? What have you tried so far? Please add more details, see [MCVE] for a guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, disabling paste functionality is not supported as this would be running in a terminal.

Answer (score -1):

You can bind key-presses and the right-button click like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack()
        self.ent = Entry(self, width=15)
        self.ent.pack()

        self.ent.bind('<Control-x>', lambda e: 'break') #disable cut
        self.ent.bind('<Control-c>', lambda e: 'break') #disable copy
        self.ent.bind('<Control-v>', lambda e: 'break') #disable paste
        self.ent.bind('<Button-3>', lambda e: 'break')  #disable right-click

root = Tk()
app = App()
mainloop()
```

Comment: OP specifically excludes Tkinter in the question.